# How to prevent DefaultTreeCellEditor from leaving Editmode?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm working on a Java program where a JTree uses a DefaultTreeCellEditor to edit its nodes. The EditorComponent is a JPanel with a JTextField and two JButtons. My problem is that only a click on the Abort-Button should leave the Editmode but every time the EditorComponent loses its focus the Editmode is also left. So how to prevent a DefaultTreeCellEditor to leave its Editmode if the EditorComponent loses its focus?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Afaik the DefaultTreeCellEditor has a method called stopCellEditing() as well as the DefaultCellEditor. This method gets called everytime before leaving the editing mode. So with overriding this method, you can integrate your own logic. For example if the button xy was pushed, or the current value is a correct one etc. etc. you return true, else you just return false and let him stay in editing mode.

Comment: I thank you very much ymene. Your answer is the first step in the right direction, but you also have to call setInvokesStopCellEditing(true);. Otherwise the stopCellEditing()-Methode is never called. The following link to a Bug note show a complete example of how to use stopCellEditing().

http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/bugParade/bugs/4436145.html

Best Regards

CrasyHorse

Comment: Glad I was able to point you in the right direction. Never worked with TreeTables so far. Just guessed its somehow simular to a normal table. So I will keep this information in mind, thank you for the update!